# make: pyuic4: command not found

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I need to develop a QGIS plugin for a project.

First, I launched the following command for the installation on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis
sudo apt-get install python-qgis
```

Then, I installed the **Plugin Builder** plugin.

Finally, I tried to follow [this simple tutorial](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html).

However, I'm stuck at the execution of the **make** command, which give to me the following error:

**make: pyuic4: command not found**

I did some research, but I'm unable to find a solution.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install the Py Qt4 dev tools:

```
sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools qt4-designer
```

Comment: Done, but the issue persist :(
Any other suggestion?

Comment: Resolved with a slightly different command:
**sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools**